# Add Microsoft Authentication to Xamarin Forms app: Invalid URI

Tags: authentication, xamarin, uri

I've spent days now trying to get my Xamarin app to accept Microsoft authentication. Right now I'm hung up with the following error when I click the sign-in button on the android app:

[Xamarin app error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZ4om.png)

Under Constants.cs I have the url set as

```
public static string ApplicationURL = @"https://CoxUR.azurewebsites.net/.auth/login/microsoftaccount/callback";
```

This is the same URI I'm using as my callback under redirect URI's in Azure:

[Azure callback uri's](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlDnl.png)

There are so many different areas to input an html address in azure, I'm not sure if I'm using the right html, or if my formatting is correct. Is it my callback URI that I'm supposed to input into ApplicationURL?

Answer (score 0):

You can read these two documents to learn how to Add Microsoft Authentication to Xamarin Form app:

1. [Add authentication to your Xamarin Forms app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users)
2. [configure-authentication-provider-microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/configure-authentication-provider-microsoft)

The `url_scheme_of_your_app` is not the  `redirect URL` you defined in the azure portal.

In the second [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-xamarin-forms-get-started-users#redirecturl), it says:

> The **url_scheme_of_your_app** in this string is the URL Scheme for your
>   mobile application. It should follow normal URL specification for a
>   protocol (use letters and numbers only, and start with a letter). You
>   should make a note of the string that you choose as you will need to
>   adjust your mobile application code with the URL Scheme in several
>   places.

Here is also a discussion about [what is url_scheme_of_your_app](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/34241):

- **Mobile App URL**: https:/yourappname.azurewebsites.net
- **url_scheme_of_your_app**: yourappname
- **redirectUriScheme**: yourappname://easyauth.callback

Answer (score 0):

I hope this one helps. I've created step by step instructions on how to implement Microsoft login in your Xamarin Forms application.

Step 1:  Sign in to the Azure portal using either a work or school account or a personal Microsoft account.

Step 2:  In the left-hand navigation pane, select the Azure Active Directory service, and then select App registrations > New registration.

Step 3:  When the Register an application page appears, enter your application's registration information.

Step 4: Select Register.

Step 5: Select Add a Redirect URI.

This step might be the answer in your question:

Step 6:  Select the type of app you're building, select Public client (mobile & desktop), and then check the first item on the Suggested Redirect URIs and enter the redirect URI (or reply URL) for your application. Then click Save.

Here's the link for your reference:
https://cedgabrang.wixsite.com/xamarintipsandtricks/post/microsoft-graph-api-xamarin-forms